# Bad positioning of slanted (italic) math accents

Tags: math-mode, fonts, plain-tex, math-fonts, computer-modern

The math accents are usually taken from textfonts (only `\vec` from the math italic font). I would like to have an italic accent over an italic letter also in math mode. To present the problem quickly I load the text italic font into `fam0`.

MWE:

```
Good: $ \ddot f $,
%
\textfont0=\tenit% to get italic accents
%
bad: $ \ddot f $

\bye
```

This results in bad positioning of the italic accent. What is happening?

I don't understand that.

Edit: The skewchar should solve all the problems with the accent spacing, shouldn't it?
[image]

Comment: I think an MWE would help here (reduce the likelihood of wrong guessing about the setup).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner that is a mwe (plaintex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah thanks, that was not clear to me from the description or the tags (I added `plain-tex` now to the tags and the title).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: There will be the same problem in LaTeX as long as you use the standard math fonts.

Comment: Ok, please keep or discard my changes as you wish.

Comment: `\textfont0=\tenit` is a really bad idea. What if you want to type `\sin x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what would be the reason for doing it: the math accents are symbols on their own and don't depend on the accentee. Anyway, your approach is flawed: see the lines 2 and 3 above the rule. And the fix I propose.

```
% your attempt
\textfont0=\tenit

1. $\ddot{f}\ddot{\mathop f}f$

2. $\ddot{x}\ddot{\mathop x}x$

3. $\sin x$

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

% revert
\textfont0=\tenrm
\newfam\italicaccents
\textfont\italicaccents=\tenit
\skewchar\textfont1=-1

\def\gobble#1{}
\def\newaccent#1{%
  \edef\temp{\expandafter\gobble#1}%
  \edef#1{\mathaccent\the\numexpr\temp+256*\the\italicaccents\relax\space}%
}
\newaccent\ddot

1. $f\ddot{f}f$

2. $x\ddot{x}x$

3. $\sin x$

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The double-dot accent character in font `\tenit` is itself skewed to the right, and this effect is added to the `\skewchar` correction of the `\teni f`, moving it too far to the right in total.

After reading rule 12 in appendix G of The TeXbook, I found that you can avoid the `\skewchar` correction by replacing the single character `f` with a `\mathpunct f` (not `\mathop`, because that might center the character vertically). Alternatively, you can set `\skewchar\teni=-1`. The italicized accent is then somewhat more to the left than the straight accent.

If you don't like that, you can use a non-math accent.

```tex
\textfont0=\tenit
$\ddot f - \ddot{\mathpunct f} - \hbox{\tenit\"{\teni f}}$
\bye
```

[image: skew madness]

Comment: do you mind scaling up your screenshot, so that readers may appreciate the details?

Comment: I have enlarged it.

Comment: Try `\mathop x` and you'll have a surprise.

Comment: @egreg, thanks, I have edited my answer.